# QPropertyAnimation отказывается работать

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, анимация, qpropertyanimation

К сути. Код должен выполнять простую анимацию. Но не выполняет.

Вот код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QPushButton, QApplication, QMainWindow, QFrame)
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QPropertyAnimation, QRect)


class window(QMainWindow, QPropertyAnimation):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Test')
        self.setGeometry(60, 60, 600, 600)
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color : blue;')

        self.MovingObj = QFrame(self)
        self.MovingObj.setFrameStyle(QFrame.Raised | QFrame.Panel)
        self.MovingObj.setStyleSheet('background-color : red')
        self.MovingObj.setGeometry(40, 40, 100, 100)

        self.but = QPushButton(self)
        self.but.setStyleSheet('background-color : pink')
        self.but.setGeometry(500, 500, 50, 50)
        self.but.setText('anime')
        self.but.clicked.connect(self.anime_thion)

    def anime_thion(self):  # Анимация
        anime = QPropertyAnimation(self.MovingObj, b'geometry')
        anime.setDuration(2500)
        anime.setStartValue(QRect(40, 40, 100, 100))
        anime.setEndValue(QRect(70, 70, 200, 200))
        anime.start()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = window()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Вам бы еще на tkinter-e немного попрактиковаться.

Comment: К сожалению практики на tkintere мне хватило. Ровно так же как и его "удобств"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте объект `anime` атрибутом класса:

```
vvvv  <----
self.anime = QPropertyAnimation(self.movingObj, b'geometry')
```

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QPushButton, QApplication, QMainWindow, 
        QFrame, QWidget)
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QPropertyAnimation, QRect)


# ??? class window(QMainWindow, QPropertyAnimation):
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Test')
        self.resize(600, 600)

        self.centralwidget = QWidget()                                   # +++               
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)                        # +++                            
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet('background-color : blue;')     # +++

        self.movingObj = QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.movingObj.setFrameStyle(QFrame.Raised | QFrame.Panel)
        self.movingObj.setStyleSheet('background-color : red')
        self.movingObj.setGeometry(40, 40, 100, 100)

        self.but = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.but.setStyleSheet('background-color : pink')
        self.but.setGeometry(500, 500, 50, 50)
        self.but.setText('anime')
        self.but.clicked.connect(self.anime_thion)

    def anime_thion(self):                                           # Анимация
# ----> vvvv <-----------------------------------------------------------------
        self.anime = QPropertyAnimation(self.movingObj, b'geometry')
        self.anime.setDuration(3500)
        self.anime.setStartValue(QRect(40, 40, 100, 100))
        self.anime.setEndValue(QRect(70, 70, 200, 200))
        self.anime.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю! А то в мою голову почему то это не дошло.